# View XPS with XPS Document API?

Tags: xps, xpsdocument, xpsviewer

How can i view an XPS using the (native Windows 7) [XPS Document API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316975%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?

Given an [XPS Object Model Package object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd372921%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (`IXpsOMPackage`), how can i render it to a bitmap or device context?

---

In the way a metafile can be ["played"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) onto a device context, how can i render an XPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a general-purpose native API for rendering XPS documents included in Windows.

You can use the [XPS OM Thumbnail Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd372787%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to render to a PNG or JPEG, but the image size is limited to 300x300 pixels.